# PyQGIS Print Layout text rotation resets on view refresh

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer

I have created a PyQGIS script that builds a Print Layout with various text labels that are rotated to read vertically on the page. The script creates the labels and places them just fine. But upon performing a view Refresh or even exporting the Layout to PDF, *all the vertical labels reset to horizontal.*

This is my first foray into building Print Layouts with scripting, so I'm sure I'm missing something basic. But I'm really in a bind if I can't get this to work properly!

**I'm running QGIS 3.18.2-Zürich on Windows 10.**

The code I'm using to place the labels is:

```
# Place vertical label
newLabel = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
newLabel.setText("Vertical Text Label")
newLabel.setFont(QFont('Tahoma', 14))
newLabel.setHAlign(Qt.AlignLeft)
newLabel.setVAlign(Qt.AlignTop)
newLabel.setRotation(270.0)

newLabel.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(4.25, 5.50, 3))

newLabel.adjustSizeToText()
layout.addLayoutItem(newLabel)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change method to rotate item and not text by using `setItemRotation` instead of `setRotation`

```py
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('demo')

newLabel = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
newLabel.setText("Vertical Text Label")
newLabel.setFont(QFont('Tahoma', 14))
newLabel.setHAlign(Qt.AlignLeft)
newLabel.setVAlign(Qt.AlignTop)
# newLabel.setRotation(270.0)
# Instead of above statement, do the following
newLabel.setItemRotation(270.0)

newLabel.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(4.25, 5.50, 3))

newLabel.adjustSizeToText()
layout.addLayoutItem(newLabel)
```